# even just alert('Hello'); won't run

Tags: javascript

I can't even get this to work. If I put a debug on the first line of javascript it never gets to it. I'm stumped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script  type="text/javascript">

    function Hello()
    {
    alert('Hello');
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have defined a function but it doesn't seem like you ever call Hello()

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to invoke the function like this: `Hello()`. Here is the working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script  type="text/javascript">

    function Hello()
    {
    alert('Hello');
    }
    
    Hello();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to call the function as follows

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

    function Hello()
    {
    alert('Hello');
    }
    Hello();     //----> function call
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script  type="text/javascript">

    function Hello()
    {
    alert('Hello');
    }
    Hello();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```